# CSS: floats "crashing" in "random" intervals

Tags: css, css-float, refresh

I have created a site which has little buttons for login and logout at the top right corner.
Inside a "header_content" div I have got another div with "float: right" (to keep it at top right corner) and inside that div I have li with link and a form with button. One has float: right and another float: left (to keep them in line).

Usually everything works fine, but for some strange reason sometimes the floats crashes and the second link "falls" through. After refreshing page everything goes to normal, untill again the crash occurs (it is not really that frequent, but still annoying though)

So is this browser based problem (I am using Chrome), or is it because I have to many "nested" floats or something else?

EDIT:

I guess I have little more floats that I thought :D
Here is the code, hope you'll get the picture ... (the one who keeps falling down is the form with button and id=right)

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="header_banner">
   .... smt
  </div>
  <div id="header_content">
     <div id="outer_left">
      ..... smt
     </div>
     <div id="outer_right">
         <li>
            <a id="left" href="........."></a>
            <form id="right" method="post" action="">                            
               <div>
                  ......
                  <button type="submit" value="value"></button>
               </div>
            </form>
        </li>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>



#header_banner, #outer_left, #left {
 float: left;
 .....
}

#outer_right, #outer_right li, #right {
 float: right;
 .....
}
```

Comment: we will definitely need an example to be able to give you any explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your floats are arguing with eachother. If you want the elements to be "in line" you could do something with "display: inline-block"

```
div.right
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.right ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you might not need to float the "in line" links. Chris's idea here looks good, maybe even use anchor tags with inline-block, if you need them boxy.

Answer (score 0):

With out an example, I suggest you float left the two links that you are trying to "keep in line". Make sure their widths combined with padding and margines do not exceed the wrapping element's width.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the display changes for reload to reload, is there the possibility that the content changes? Even a invisible space character or a border can take up too much space so that the container is too small to float them in line.
Have you tried to enlargen the container by say 50px and test if the behaviour continues?

Comment: No, there is only static content on the site. And this also occurs on different pages with different types of content (yet always the same content within one page). Container is about twice the size of the width of both link/buttons.

Comment: Hm, then I would try to simplify the markup and the css as much as possible. Blank HTML-File with only what is needed for the broken links. Then add the content and the css part by part and look what happens.
Have you tried using different browsers?
Can you make an example page and post the link so we can examine the HTML and CSS and experiment with your page?